# bootstrap 5 dropdown <ul> container is not responsive and taking extra width

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

The sub menu container is not responsive and taking extra place outside of container. Here is my code that I used from Bootstrap official site.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Link
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and after browsing some related questions in Stack Overflow, I finally came up a solution. What you need to do is just add `min-width: 100%` attribute to the dropdown menu in css, please see the code below.

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu.show {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```